# Linux AF_UNIX socket states

Tags: linux, sockets

I am using a AF_UNIX socket. It goes into listen waiting for something to connect.
When I look at /proc/net/unix the St column shows 01 and the Path matches the filename that the AF_UNIX socket is using.

It all seems to work I can connect to it and pass data.

I am just curious that for AF_INET sockets when I look at /proc/net/tcp on ports I believe to be listening it has an St column of 0A which seems to be TCP_LISTEN.

Is it expected that when an AF_UNIX socket is listening for connections that the St column will be 01 and not 0A ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I don't know what the state of a unix socket will be while listening, but it certainly won't be TCP_LISTEN - TCP isn't spoken over unix sockets.

Okay, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183140/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-contents-of-proc-net-unix) is most helpful.  It pointed me at [this line](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9e6c269de404bef2fb50b9407e988083a0805e3b/net/unix/af_unix.c#L3272) in the kernel source, which says that that `St` column is:

```
            s->sk_socket ?
            (s->sk_state == TCP_ESTABLISHED ? SS_CONNECTED : SS_UNCONNECTED) :
            (s->sk_state == TCP_ESTABLISHED ? SS_CONNECTING : SS_DISCONNECTING),
```

...which I don't grok the logic of, but seems to be returning `SS_UNCONNECTED`.